# Changes in upstream repo during open pull request ? (How) should I merge in my fork?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-fork

I've forked a repo on Github, added some code, pushed these changes to my remote repo and submitted a pull request to the upstream repo.

While now waiting for the pull request to be handled I notice there happened some commits in the upstream repo.

I should merge these commits back in my fork because I have to adapt my changes to the latest version in the upstream repo.

I think I have now two options:

- do a 'normal' pull and merge, but then when (if) my pullrequest gets merged in the upstream repo it will clutter its history with my merge commit.
- do a rebase merge, this would avoid the merge commit but as far I know I shouldn't do this because I've already pushed my changes.

How to handle this properly?

Comment: Addition as per Yawar's answer: for small bug fixes I work on the upstream's repo 'next' (= 'develop') branch, for adding features I work on a dedicated feature branch, so I never work on the master branch directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebase rewrites history which can cause trouble for branches where multiple collaborators are going to work on the same branch.

I assume your Pull-Request branch is something finished where you don't expect anybody else's pushes.

So I think the rebase is perfectly fine.

Comment: "I assume your Pull-Request branch is something finished where you don't expect anybody else's pushes." This means that even for small things like bug fixes I should do it in a dedicated branch rather than work on the upstream's repo 'next' branch as I used to (see my above comment) right ?

Comment: Yes. Smaller dedicated branches are easier to handle.

Answer (score 1):

When you push new commits to your GitHub fork, GitHub will automatically update the pull request that you opened and 'expire' any old commits that are outdated by rebases. You don't have to worry about what will happen to the PR, it will just do the right thing.

By the way, you didn't mention which branch you're working on, so maybe it's the `master` branch. I would highly recommend working on a feature branch even in your own fork, just because that gives you the flexibility to work on multiple PRs.